# Why I can't run karma unit test?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

When I try to run `npm run test:unit` in AngularJS I have the next error

```
19 05 2020 13:27:06.476:ERROR [karma-server]: Server start failed on port 9877: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: This is a very generic error saying that at some point in your code you are accessing a variable that is undefined. `person.name` would yield that error if `person` was `undefined`

Comment: Yeah I know but that all that printed to me after run test:unit

Comment: Can you share more information regarding the `package.json` where `test:unit` is located and more info regarding the `karma.conf` file?